# How do I use Cloudwatch metrics only after last start of EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am attaching a CloudWatch alarm through a lambda function which starts an instance, attaches an alarm and then processes an event.
Here's my code for attaching the alarm.

```
def attach_alarm(instance):
    cloudwatch_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    alarm_name = 'CPUUsageAlarm'
    alarms = cloudwatch_client.describe_alarms(AlarmNames=[alarm_name])
    logger.info(f"Active alarms found : {alarms}")
    cloudwatch_client.delete_alarms(AlarmNames=[alarm_name])
    logger.info(f"Alarm deleted : {alarm_name}")
    metric_name = 'CPUUtilization'
    namespace = 'AWS/EC2'
    comparison_operator = 'LessThanThreshold'
    threshold = 5.0
    evaluation_periods = 3
    period = 300
    alarm_description = 'Alarm to stop instance when CPU usage drops below 5% for more than 2 minutes'
    actions_enabled = True
    alarm_actions = [f'arn:aws:automate:us-east-2:ec2:stop']  
    cloudwatch_client.put_metric_alarm(
        AlarmName=alarm_name,
        ComparisonOperator=comparison_operator,
        EvaluationPeriods=evaluation_periods,
        MetricName=metric_name,
        Namespace=namespace,
        Period=period,
        Statistic='Average',
        Threshold=threshold,
        ActionsEnabled=actions_enabled,
        AlarmActions=alarm_actions,
        AlarmDescription=alarm_description,
        Dimensions=[{'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value':instance}],
        TreatMissingData='notBreaching' 
    )
    logger.info(f'Alarm attached to instance {instance}')
```

However, when I have multiple events which I am processing at a batch count of 1, the lambda is expected to start the instance, process the event and once the alarm is breached (in 300 s here) the instance stops. For the next event, the moment the alarm is attached, the alarm is always breached from metrics of the previous event processing. How can I overcome this and avoid stopping the instance as soon as it starts?

Thanks!